# Constant curvature manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, big-list, reference-request

In two different books I found these two related statements.

- The book by Jost defines a ``locally symmetric space" as one for which the curvature tensor is constant and which is geodesically complete.
- Andreas' book attributes to Cartan a theorem that a space is locally symmetric if and only if its curvature tensor is constant. Where he defines a space to be locally symmetric if about every point there is a geodesic reflecting isometry.

I could not trace this theorem of Cartan anywhere else nor does Andreas' book give a reference. I would like to know some reference which would prove this stuff and resolve the apparent definition conflict between the above two statements.

Further I came across these 3 statements about classifying constant curvature spaces,

- If the isometry group is transitive on points on the manifold, then the scalar
  curvature  is constant.
- If the isometry group is transitive on all one-dimensional subspaces
  of tangent spaces, then the Ricci curvature tensor is a scalar multiple of the metric.
  tensor
- If the isometry group is transitive on all two-dimensional subspaces
  of tangent spaces, then the sectional curvature is constant on all
  two-dimensional subspaces of tangent spaces.

I have an understanding of why the first statement is true but I would like to know some reference which explains the other two statements.

Further call a space to be homogeneous if it is quotient of some Lie Group mod a closed subgroup. Then in physics literature one finds a statement of the kind that an "isotropic and homogeneous space-time is of constant curvature". I would like to know what is the precise mathematical meaning of this statement.

Further I would also like to know a reference for the fact that a maximally symmetric space always has constant curvature and how being maximally symmetric fits in with being "isotropic and homogeneous".

Many sources refer me to the volumes by Kobayashi and Nomizu or the book by Besse or Spivak for discussion on constant curvature spaces but unfortunately I don't have access to these books. It would be great if some online reference like lecture notes/expository review paper on constant curvature spaces could be linked which clarifies the above questions.

In the books on Riemannian Geometry that I have access to like the ones by Gallot et al,Andreas or Jost, I can't see much of any discussion on these topics.

{In all the above statements I suppose the Riemann Christoffel connection is being assumed. It would be interesting to know how much of the things hold for a general affine connection.}

Comment: The result you mention at the begining of your post should be in Helgason's book, I imagine.

Comment: By the way, when making such multiple questions, marking them with numbers or something like that so that one can answer only a subquestion and be able to identify it easily would be nice!

Comment: Anirbit, could you tell us what Jost says verbatim? Maybe something about the curvature tensor being covariant-constant? As Jose says, the definition you ascribe to Jost doesn't look right. 

Comment: In Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* (is this the right book by Jost?), Definition 5.3.3, one reads that *A complete riemannian manifold with $\nabla R \equiv 0$ is called locally symmetric.*  I believe this is not a correct definition: a locally symmetric space need not be complete.  (Both Besse and Helgason agre with this.)

Comment: In addition to Helgason's "Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces" which Mariano already mentioned, you can also try Armand Borel's "Semisimple groups and Riemannian symmetric spaces", Ottmar Loos' "Symmetric Spaces" vols 1 and 2, or Joseph Wolf's "Spaces of constant curvature". I've only personally used Helgason and Borel; Loos and Wolf were recommended to me by others. 

Comment: Ah, I should also add that there's an okay treatment in O'Neill's "Semi-Riemannian geometry" (chapter 8). And in a pinch you can always look up definitions and more references on the Springer EOM http://eom.springer.de/S/s091710.htm  And since you asked about online lecture notes, you may want to try Eschenburg's http://www.math.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf

Comment: I had a typo in the quote I gave from the book by Jost. (corrected the typo) It is the definition 5.3.3 of Jost that I was referring to as Jose as pointed out. 



Comment: So is the conclusion that Jost's definition is incorrect?

Though one can easily see that if there exists a geodesic reflecting global isometry about every point then such a manifold is geodesically complete and also Riemann homogeneous. 

So basically can we look at the Cartan's theorem as a complete classification of constant Riemann curvature manifolds?

Are there other well-known classifications theorems of constant curvature(scalar/Riemann/Sectional/Ricci) manifolds? 


Comment: I would like to know more about the connection between being "maximally symmetric" and "isotropic and homogeneous" which no one has till now touched upon. 

Comment: @Willie
Those lecture notes are very nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anirbit, whether one chooses to include completeness in the definition may be regarded as a matter of taste. For local theorems, completeness is irrelevant; for global ones, it's vital. So the difference between Jost's and Besse's definition is marginal. However, your original statement, involving scalar curvature, means something almost but not quite entirely unlike the corrected statement!

Comment: @Tim
Could you elaborate on the possible analogous statement with scalar curvature that you seem to be referring to in the last line of your comment?



Comment: Well, in 4 dimensions, say, the curvature tensor has 20 independent components (in general, the formula is $n^2(n^2-1)/12$). If the curvature is covariant-constant then all of these components are determined by their value at a point. The scalar curvature is just one of these components; to say that it is constant tells you nothing about the remaining 19 components. (There are existence theorems for constant scalar curvature metrics, but I don't have the statements at my fingertips.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is difficult to reconcile your first two statements, because they are actually wrong as written!

A riemannian manifold is *locally symmetric* if and only if the Riemann curvature tensor is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection.  This condition was studied by Élie Cartan, who classified them using his classification of real semisimple Lie algebras.  My favourite reference for this is Besse's *Einstein manifolds*, Chapter 7F, from where I quote the following theorem:

> **10.72 Theorem** (Elie Cartan). For a Riemannian manifold (not necessarily complete) the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) $DR = 0$;
>
> (ii) the geodesic symmetry $s_p$ around any point $p$ (which is defined only locally) is an isometry.
>
> For a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ the two following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (iii) for every point $p$ in $M$ the geodesic symmetry around $p$ is well defined and is an isometry;
>
> (iv) the manifold $M$ is a homogeneous space $G/H$ where $G$ is a connected Lie group, $H$ a compact subgroup of $G$, and where there exists an involutive automorphism $\sigma$ of the group $G$ for which, if $S$ denotes the fixed point set of $\sigma$ and $S_e$ its connected component of the identity one has $S_e \subset H \subset S$. Moreover the Riemannian metric under consideration on $G/H$ is invariant under $G$.
>
> Furthermore: if $(M, g)$ satisfies (iii) or (iv), then it satisfies (i) and (ii). If $(M, g)$ satisfies (i) or (ii) and if  it is simply connected and complete then it satisfies (iii) and (iv).
>
> **10.76 Definition**.  A Riemannian manifold is said to be *locally symmetric* if it satisfies (i) or (ii) above; it is said to be *symmetric* if it satisfies (iii) or (iv).

I suspect the source of the confusion might be with the meaning of "constant curvature", which usually means constant sectional curvature (or perhaps parallel Riemann curvature) and not constant scalar curvature, which is a much weaker condition.

Concerning your final parenthetic question, there is a theorem of Ambrose and Singer, reformulated by Kostant, which says that a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is *locally homogeneous* if and only if it admits a metric connection with parallel torsion and parallel curvature.  It is locally symmetric if (and only if) the connection is torsion-free.

Comment: I figured out that I have institutional access to the book by Besse on Springer website. Thanks for this precise reference. 



Answer (score 6):

First, a clarification.  When you say "the isometry group is transitive on all one-dimensional subspaces of tangent spaces", what this really means is that for any $v\in T_p M$ and $w\in T_q M$ with $|v| = |w|$, there is an isometry $f:M\rightarrow M$ with $f(p) = q$ and $d_p f v = w$.

This immediately implies that $Ric_p(v) = Ric_q(w)$ for any vectors $v$ and $w$ of the same length.  This implies that the polarization of this to $Ric(\cdot, \cdot)$ are also the same (meaning $Ric_p(v,v') = Ric_q(d_p f v, d_p f v')$ for any isometry $f$ mapping $p$ to $q$).

Now, fix a $p\in M$ and let $G_p\subseteq $Iso$(M)$ be the subgroup of all isometries which fix $p$.  By the assumption of the second bullet point, $G_p$ acts transitively on the sphere in $T_p M$ (i.e., $G_p$ takes any unit vector to any other unit vector).  It follows that the representation of $G_p$ on $T_p M$ is irreducible.

Now, let $g$ denote the inner product at $T_p M$ and let $P:T_pM\rightarrow T_p M$ be defined by $g(P v, w) = Ric_p(v,w)$.  It's easy to see that $P$ will be $G_p$ invariant, and hence, by Schur's lemma, a multiple of the identity.  That is, $Ric_p$ is a multiple of the metric.

The statement about sectional curvatures is easier:  Curvature is an invariant of the metric, and hence so is sectional curvature. By the assumption of bullet point 3, there is an isometry of $G$ which takes any point to any other point and moves any 2-plane to any other 2-plane.  But then the sectional curvature of any 2-plane at any point is equal to the sectional curvature of any 2-plane at any other point, that is, $M$ has constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @Jason
Thanks a lot for your great explanation.

I was wondering as an extension of the third bullet point as to what can one say about the curvature if one is told that the isometry group is transitive on the set of tangent spaces (and not just on every 2-plane)

If I know that the Riemannian manifold is a homogeneous space and that the isometry group is transitive on the set of tangent spaces then can one say anything about the curvature? 

Comment: First, homogeneous automatically implies the isometry group is transitive on the set of tangent spaces: for p and q in M, the fact that it's homogeneous implies there is an isometry f with f(p) = q.  Then d_p f will automatically map TpM to TqM.  As to your next question, there isn't much which can be said in this generality, but, for example, once you know all the curvatures of every 2plane at one point, you automatically know them everywhere.  Compact homogeneous manifolds with finite fundamental group always have another metric which is still homogeneous and has sectional curvature >=0.

Comment: Probably I wasn't very clear. I was meaning homogeneous in the sense of the manifold being diffeomorphic to some G/H. In your initial explanation could you clarify why the map P with the property you are looking for should exist? Or to put it otherwise, why given any v should there exist a v' such that g(v',w)=Ric(v,w) for all w? {I can see the rest of the argument assuming the existence of the map P}

Comment: I see - I meant homogeneous as in the (Riemannian) manifold is isometric to some G/H.  To show P exists, pick an orthonormal basis $e_i$ for TpM.  Create the symmetric n x n matrix $A = (A_{ij})$ where $A_{ij} = Ric(e_i, e_j)$.  Then define $P$ by declaring it to be given by $A$ on the basis $e_i$.  Then, for example, we can figure out $P(e_1)$ by pairing it with every e_i:  we get $g(P(e_1), e_i) = A_{1i} = Ric(e_1, e_i)$ as desired.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. In connection to the first bullet point I noticed that the combination of Definition 5.3.2 and Theorem 5.3.2 in the book by Jost together implies that if the isometry group acts transitively on the manifold then the entire Riemann Curvature Tensor is constant. Then shouldn't there be a weaker criteria which makes just the scalar curvature constant?

Comment: Well, the problem is that scalar curvature is a VERY weak invariant.  For example, the Kazdan-Warner theorem states that if f:M->R is any smooth function which is negative somewhere, then f is the scalar curvature of some metric on M.  Similarly, if there is a metric on M with positive scalar curvature, than any smooth function f:M->R is the scalar curvature of some metric (but there are obstructions to positive scalar curvature metrics!).  I'm not sure what this weaker criteria would be, since every compact homogeneous space actually admits an Einstein metric (constant Ricci curvature)....

Comment: Thanks for these leads. I will look them up.

How about being just maximally symmetric? (i.e a n-dim Riemannian Manifold having all the n(n+1)/2 Killing fields) Isn't that a weaker criteria to allow just a constant scalar curvature and still allowing a non-trivial Riemann curvature tensor? 

{Though I would like to see a good reference on maximally symmetric spaces}

Comment: In the book "Transformation Groups" by Kobayashi (and perhaps others), they have the following theorem:  If the isometry group (of a complete manifold) has dimension n(n+1)/2, then the manifold has constant curvature.  Further, there are restrictions one what the dimension of the isometry group can be.  I don't remember anything specific off hand, but there are results in the flavor of "If the isometry group has dim at least k, then it automatically has dim n(n+1)/2."  (This is related to, but harder than, the fact that there aren't many simple groups in a given range of dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I will look that up.
Do you have an example of a homogeneous manifold (in either the topological or the riemannian sense) which is not symmetric? Although we know that any symmetric riemannian manifold is necessarily riemann homogeneous, it should be nice to build intuition about why the converse may not be true. 



Comment: A generic homogeneous manifold is NOT symmetric. So, for example, in dimension 3, $S^3$ and $\mathbb{R}P^3$ ARE symmetric, but all other lens spaces are NOT (though they are all homogeneous). As per Jos$\acute{\text{e}}$'s comment above (point 4), there must be an involution which has H in its fixed point set. But these involutions have all been classified (though I don't know of a good reference for this), and this just doesn't happen generically. Further, the fundamental group of a symmetric space is always abelian, so, G/H where H is a finite nonabelian group is another example.

Comment: @ Jason DeVito all the $ L(p,1) $ lens spaces are homogeneous for $ SU(2) $, but what Lie groups act transitively on generic $ L(p,q) $? I was just about to post this question to stack exchange, should I still do it?

Comment: @Ian:  They are not homogeneous unless $q=\pm 1$.  This is found in Wolf's classification of space forms.  I'm not sure why I wrote that above.  (Also, my claim that homogeneous spaces admit Einstein metrics is wrong, as well).